# Java Applet with tooltip

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I have a `JApplet` that contains a `JEditorPane`. The `JEditorPane` has a tooltip text associated with it. The first time the applet is loaded, the tooltip shows correctly but after I click somewhere in the HTML page, outside the applet's area, the tooltip stops working. I suspect it has to do with the applet losing focus.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Best regards,
Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "(...) naming the applet element within the html document and then 
using javascript onfocus to send the browser focus to the element."

Source: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t671396-applet-focus-issue.html